# Show error message when ng-maxlength is used

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to show an error message when I have reached the max limit (32) for my login name. The code pasted before is what I would normally use, but for some reason it's not working. The only difference is that I'm not using a modal box, but just the text box if that could be the issue? Thank you!

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.loginName.$invalid && !myForm.loginName.$pristine }">
                                <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">Login
                                    Name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                           id="loginName" name="loginName"
                                           ng-model="targetEntity.loginName" required placeholder="Login Name"
                                           ng-maxlength="32">
                                    <p ng-show="myForm.loginName.$invalid && !myForm.loginName.$pristine"
                                       class="help-block">Mandatory field, maximum length 255 characters.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: You are only checking for invalid and pristine in your error message. You need to check for the character count in the input, having it at the max length does not make it invalid.

Comment: So what would I have to put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$error`.

```
  <div ng-messages="myForm.loginName.$error" style="color:red">
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Max length reached</div>
  </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gZKFJcTgzeGW3UDrYqIl?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You also can also use it in more direct way since $error is a object provided by angular. The way bellow for example:

```
ng-show="myForm.loginName.$error.maxlength"
```

But I would recommend using ngMessages as previously mentioned because it's easier.